# How to sync with gdocs and gtask in android?

Tags: android, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I have a simple notepad and a to do list. I want to do a sync of the text with the notepad and gdocs (google docs) over net and also want to sync the to do list with the gtasks (google tasks). I know that this is into a simple task that can be explained in a single note, but please help me with some sample, code snippet and links that can help me start of in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Build a SyncAdapter ([1](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/), [2](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253858/why-does-contentresolver-requestsync-not-trigger-a-sync/))
2. Use [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) as an abstraction layer to talk to the google docs api.
3. Fill the data you find into an Android [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) that stores your notes.  The same ContentProvider is your interface to view/edit notes.

Comment: Ahhhh.... you made my day... thank you very very much for the help.... I will sure this will work..... Will post some comments to reach you if i need any help... thank you very much for this help...