# Can't perform Sync (onPerformSync is not called)

Tags: android, android-service

I follow this title [Why does ContentResolver.requestSync not trigger a sync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253858/why-does-contentresolver-requestsync-not-trigger-a-sync) but Sync method does not appear in Account&Sync in Setting screen. I think that **onPerformSync()** is not called. I try to debug but no error log found. Here are my code :

**syncAdapter.xml**

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:accountType="@string/ACCOUNT_TYPE"
android:contentAuthority="@string/AUTHORITY"
android:userVisible="true"
android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
```

/>

**SyncService.java**

```
public class CalendarSyncService extends Service{
private static SyncAdapterImpl sSyncAdapter = null;
private static String list_event_ids;
private static Requestor requestor;

public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate ();
    if (sSyncAdapter == null)
        sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapterImpl(this);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
}

public class SyncAdapterImpl extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {

    Context context;
    public SyncAdapterImpl(Context context) {
        super(context, true);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account arg0, Bundle arg1, String arg2,
            ContentProviderClient arg3, SyncResult arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("thuutai", "Perform Sync Call");

        try {
            CalendarSyncService.performSync(context);
        } catch (DOMException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**I call it in here**

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, false);
        params.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_DO_NOT_RETRY, false);
        params.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, false);
        ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(selectedAccount, getString(R.string.AUTHORITY), params, 3600);
        ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(selectedAccount, getString(R.string.AUTHORITY), true);

        ContentResolver.requestSync(selectedAccount, getString(R.string.AUTHORITY), params);}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <service android:name=".service.CalendarSyncService" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
         android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
```

I tested in Nexus S Android 4.0.
Thank for your reading!

Comment: maybe that's same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810659/android-syncadapter-retry/16294867

Comment: <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />  In this line need to give our package name or this is the common declaration for all projects??

Comment: problem is you are saying don't update when you set sync_extras_manual to false it should be true

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes this method won't be called due to similar sync in progress. You can check it and cancel with following code:

```
if (ContentResolver.isSyncPending(yourAccount, yourAuthority)  ||
    ContentResolver.isSyncActive(yourAccount, yourAuthority)) {
  Log.i("ContentResolver", "SyncPending, canceling");
  ContentResolver.cancelSync(yourAccount, yourAuthority);
}
```

Comment: Everyone need use this!

Answer (score 1):

Something that you can try is:

```
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, AUTHORITY, true);
```

I tried setting the `isAlwaysSyncable` flag but it did not work for me (although that may have been a different issue).

Answer (score -1):

You must force the manual synchronization.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
params.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
ContentResolver.requestSync(selectedAccount, getString(R.string.AUTHORITY), params);
```