# ContentResolver.requestSync in Sync Adapter is not working in Android

Tags: java, android, background-process, stub, android-syncadapter

I am trying to write a sync adapter with 'StubProvider' and 'StubAuthenticator', i followed the offical guidelines, my code is running without any errors but 'onPerformSync()' is NOT getting called, i tried everything but no use.

My full project can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/48bgj3wweehaieu/MyApplication.zip?dl=0

Here are the classes I am using:

Class MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // Constants
    // The authority for the sync adapter's content provider
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.syncadaptertest.StubProvider";
    // An account type, in the form of a domain name
    public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.syncadaptertest";
    // The account name
    public static final String ACCOUNT = "dummyaccount";
    // Instance fields
    Account mAccount;

    private ImageButton mRefreshBtn = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRefreshBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.refreshBtn);
        mRefreshBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Create the dummy account
        mAccount = CreateSyncAccount(this);

    }

    /**
     * Create a new dummy account for the sync adapter
     *
     * @param context The application context
     */
    public static Account CreateSyncAccount(Context context) {
        // Create the account type and default account
        Account newAccount = new Account(ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        // Get an instance of the Android account manager
        AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) context.getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
        /*
         * Add the account and account type, no password or user data
         * If successful, return the Account object, otherwise report an error.
         */
        if (accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, null, null)) {
            /*
             * If you don't set android:syncable="true" in
             * in your <provider> element in the manifest,
             * then call context.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1)
             * here.
             */
        } else {
            /*
             * The account exists or some other error occurred. Log this, report it,
             * or handle it internally.
             */
        }
        return newAccount;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        onRefreshButtonClick(v);
    }



    /**
     * Respond to a button click by calling requestSync(). This is an
     * asynchronous operation.
     *
     * This method is attached to the refresh button in the layout
     * XML file
     *
     * @param v The View associated with the method call,
     * in this case a Button
     */
    public void onRefreshButtonClick(View v) {

        // Pass the settings flags by inserting them in a bundle
        Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle();
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
        settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
        /*
         * Request the sync for the default account, authority, and
         * manual sync settings
         */
        ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(mAccount, AUTHORITY, 1);
        ContentResolver.requestSync(mAccount, AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);

        if(ContentResolver.isSyncActive(mAccount, AUTHORITY))
        {
            Log.d("testing1","testttt");
        }
        if(ContentResolver.isSyncPending(mAccount, AUTHORITY))
        {
            Log.d("testing2","testttt2");
        }

        List<SyncInfo> myList = ContentResolver.getCurrentSyncs();

    }

}
```

Class For Stub Authenticator

```
    public class Authenticator extends AbstractAccountAuthenticator {
    // Simple constructor
    public Authenticator(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    // Editing properties is not supported
    @Override
    public Bundle editProperties(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r, String s) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    // Don't add additional accounts
    @Override
    public Bundle addAccount(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            String s,
            String s2,
            String[] strings,
            Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }
    // Ignore attempts to confirm credentials
    @Override
    public Bundle confirmCredentials(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            Account account,
            Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        return null;
    }
    // Getting an authentication token is not supported
    @Override
    public Bundle getAuthToken(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            Account account,
            String s,
            Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    // Getting a label for the auth token is not supported
    @Override
    public String getAuthTokenLabel(String s) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    // Updating user credentials is not supported
    @Override
    public Bundle updateCredentials(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            Account account,
            String s, Bundle bundle) throws NetworkErrorException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    // Checking features for the account is not supported
    @Override
    public Bundle hasFeatures(
            AccountAuthenticatorResponse r,
            Account account, String[] strings) throws NetworkErrorException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Class AuthenticatorService

```
    public class AuthenticatorService extends Service {

    // Instance field that stores the authenticator object
    private Authenticator mAuthenticator;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Create a new authenticator object
        mAuthenticator = new Authenticator(this);
    }
    /*
     * When the system binds to this Service to make the RPC call
     * return the authenticator's IBinder.
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mAuthenticator.getIBinder();
    }
}
```

Class SyncService

```
    public class SyncService extends Service {
    // Storage for an instance of the sync adapter
    private static SyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;
    // Object to use as a thread-safe lock
    private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();
    /*
     * Instantiate the sync adapter object.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        /*
         * Create the sync adapter as a singleton.
         * Set the sync adapter as syncable
         * Disallow parallel syncs
         */
        synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
            if (sSyncAdapter == null) {
                sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Return an object that allows the system to invoke
     * the sync adapter.
     *
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        /*
         * Get the object that allows external processes
         * to call onPerformSync(). The object is created
         * in the base class code when the SyncAdapter
         * constructors call super()
         */
        return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
    }
}
```

Class StubProvider

```
public class StubProvider extends ContentProvider {
    /*
     * Always return true, indicating that the
     * provider loaded correctly.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return true;
    }
    /*
     * Return no type for MIME type
     */
    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }
    /*
     * query() always returns no results
     *
     */
    @Override
    public Cursor query(
            Uri uri,
            String[] projection,
            String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs,
            String sortOrder) {
        return null;
    }
    /*
     * insert() always returns null (no URI)
     */
    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        return null;
    }
    /*
     * delete() always returns "no rows affected" (0)
     */
    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }
    /*
     * update() always returns "no rows affected" (0)
     */
    public int update(
            Uri uri,
            ContentValues values,
            String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Class SyncAdapter

```
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    private final AccountManager mAccountManager;

    public SyncAdapter(Context context, boolean autoInitialize) {
        super(context, autoInitialize);
        mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
        Log.d("udinic", "onPerformSync for account[" + account.name + "]");
        try {
            // TODO Updating local tv shows

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're providing a lot of code, but what exactly isn't working? Please describe what you are trying to achieve, what the expected result is and what the actual result is.

Comment: if `onPerformSync` is getting called, so what is your problem?

Comment: silly me, i just edited ....   'onPerformSync' is NOT getting called.

Comment: Do you resolve the problem?, i have the same problem

Comment: check this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5255360/1016367

Answer (score 35):

Are you sure it's not working?

Remember that Sync Adapter is run on a Bound Service which is not in the same process, so your Log.d() in onPerformSync() will not show in the LogCat under your app main process but in the process that the Sync Adapter is using.

Try removing the filter in the LogCat : instead of "Show only selected application" select "No filters".

Comment: This really solved my 2 days old headache. Thanks :)

Comment: The same thing happened to me. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Wow, after hours and hours of debugging this was the golden clue. After selecting "No filters" I saw the logs and realised I hadn't implemented dynamic permission handling. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks @Raphael It has been almost an hour  I looking into this!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out in high priority with proper explanation.  I read it most of the places but ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify your account_type on the metadata xml of the sync adapter?

Your xml discriptor should be like this

```
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
    android:accountType="com.syncadaptertest"
    android:userVisible="true"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>
```

And most importantly it should be declared on your AndroidManifest file

```
<service
        android:name=".sync.ContactSyncService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/sync_contact" />
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:process=":sync" from android manifest