# Android App getting killed from SyncAdapter

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I've a SyncAdapter that gets called during the initial onboarding process (Login/Signup) that deals with contacts to find a user's contacts already using the system.

While the SyncAdapter is running, the app gets killed almost every time (9 out of 10 times) on a **particular device (Moto G)**.

My initial thoughts were the app is getting killed due to the limited available RAM of the device. So, I [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3192348/1796173) to confirm the theory:

```
@Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority,
                          ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
    ActivityManager.MemoryInfo mi = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
    long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
    Log.d(TAG, "Available: " + availableMegs);
    Log.d(TAG, "Low Memory: " + mi.lowMemory);
}
```

And turns out the RAM might not be an issue, since the Logs looks like this:

```
03-09 11:38:34.444 19193-21339/mypackage.sandbox D/SyncAdapter: Available: 252
03-09 11:38:34.445 19193-21339/mypackage.sandbox D/SyncAdapter: Low Memory: false
```

Futher in logs I found this:

```
 03-09 11:38:35.233 865-1610/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 19193:mypackage.sandbox/u0a579 (adj 0): depends on provider com.android.providers.contacts/.ContactsProvider2 in dying proc android.process.acore
```

It seems like the application is being killed since the contacts application/provider is getting killed.

I'm not sure how much relevant is [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2mvhkh) I found on reddit.

#### What are the ways I can prevent my app getting killed when it is still in FOREGROUND ?

One way I think its possible is if I can defer the notification that the contacts have been modified. It will prevent contacts provider from firing up and getting killed, in turn my application won't get killed. Please refer to [point no 7 on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255360/1796173). If so, how can I defer the notification ?

#### Update:

I have even made sure that the notification to contacts is deferred by not changing any contact. Still the problem persists.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like this is a common issue and not a problem with your app: https://www.google.se/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%22dying+proc+android.process.acore%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=vdjrVurwJ8qWwAOvlZnoAQ

Comment: it would be great if I can figure out some workaround.

Comment: 1) What is the behavior on other devices other than MOTO G ? 
2) What else your app does before `sync` process starts, it seems that something else is happening which is causing contacts provider to crash. Check you default contacts or SMS app

Comment: It gets killed while reading the contacts. There isn't anything else going on.  I've tested on Moto G3, Sony, OnePlus, Nexus, Lenovo & Samsung devices as well, it works fine. What should I check in default contacts or SMS app? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a niche device specific problem. Is this device too important for your end product? Creating custom Application class and catching Error (not Exception) might help you in debugging.

Comment: @AmitK.Saha Maybe a device specific problem. I already have a custom Application class that does what you recommend. The thing is it also not able to detect anything since the application gets killed. There's no exception at all. And also I can't be sure if it won't happen on other devices in the market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're running into a [TransactionTooLargeException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)? It occurs when data bundled with an Intent is taking more space than the 1MB limit. Seeing the ContactsProvider in your log, it may have happened because the user's contacts database is too large. The sad thing about this exception is that it happens at the system level. Your app gets killed without ever getting a chance to catch (or: report) the problem. The only way to catch this exception is by keeping a close eye on logcat.

As for your question of how to prevent the SyncAdapter from crashing your app. Are you running the SyncAdapter in a separate process? If you just followed the sample/tutorial code then you are. If not, look up `android:process=":sync"` in the [training page](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html#DeclareSyncAdapterManifest).  When run in a separate process, crashes in your SyncAdapter shouldn't affect the rest of your app. At least not directly. Your users will see an 'app has crashed' dialog, but app components running in other processes will continue running normally.

Comment: I've not seen `TransactionTooLargeException` in the logs, so really can't say if that is killing the application. It should show up in the system logs.
Thanks for the separate process tip, it should solve my purpose. I'd still keep the question open to encourage more insights. Thanks a lot!